# Is there a better way to write this MS SQL Server query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Hello and thank you for your time, I am new to SQL. Currently using MS SQL SERVER

my question:

Is there a better way to write this query? -- most important

I am also not sure if I understand  the question, am I suposed to sort by order_total or something else?

the question to which the query answers:

Write a SELECT statement that returns one row for each customer that has orders with these columns:

- The email_address column from the Customers table
- A count of the number of orders aliased as order_count
- The total amount for each order aliased as order_total (Hint: First, subtract the discount amount from the price. Then, multiply by the quantity.)
- Return only those rows where the customer has more than 1 order.
- Sort the result set in descending sequence by the sum of the line item amounts.

the query:

```
SELECT  c.email_address, t1.customer_orders, t2.order_total
FROM customers c
JOIN
    (SELECT customer_id, order_id,
        COUNT(customer_id) OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id) AS customer_orders
        FROM orders) AS t1
    ON c.customer_id = t1.customer_id
JOIN (SELECT oi.order_id,
        SUM((oi.item_price - oi.discount_amount) * oi.quantity)  AS order_total
        FROM order_items oi
        GROUP BY order_id) AS t2
    ON t2.order_id = t1.order_id
WHERE customer_orders > 1
ORDER BY order_total DESC
;
```

or:

```
SELECT  c.email_address, t1.customer_orders, t2.order_total
FROM customers c
JOIN
    (SELECT customer_id, order_id,
        COUNT(customer_id) OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id) AS customer_orders
        FROM orders) AS t1
    ON c.customer_id = t1.customer_id
JOIN (SELECT oi.order_id,
        COUNT(oi.quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY oi.order_id) AS items_quantity,
        SUM((oi.item_price - oi.discount_amount) * oi.quantity)  AS order_total
        FROM order_items oi
        GROUP BY order_id, oi.quantity) AS t2
    ON t2.order_id = t1.order_id
WHERE customer_orders > 1
ORDER BY items_quantity DESC
;
```

database:

```
USE MASTER;
go
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS my_guitar_shop;
go
CREATE DATABASE my_guitar_shop;
go
USE my_guitar_shop;
go
-- create the tables for the database
CREATE TABLE categories (
  category_id        INT            IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  category_name      VARCHAR(255)   NOT NULL      UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE products (
  product_id         INT            IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  category_id        INT            NOT NULL,
  product_code       VARCHAR(10)    NOT NULL      UNIQUE,
  product_name       VARCHAR(255)   NOT NULL,
  description        TEXT           NOT NULL,
  list_price         DECIMAL(10,2)  NOT NULL,
  discount_percent   DECIMAL(10,2)  NOT NULL      DEFAULT 0.00,
  date_added         DATETIME                     DEFAULT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT products_fk_categories
    FOREIGN KEY (category_id)
    REFERENCES categories (category_id)
);

CREATE TABLE customers (
  customer_id           INT            IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  email_address         VARCHAR(255)   NOT NULL      UNIQUE,
  password              VARCHAR(60)    NOT NULL,
  first_name            VARCHAR(60)    NOT NULL,
  last_name             VARCHAR(60)    NOT NULL,
  shipping_address_id   INT                          DEFAULT NULL,
  billing_address_id    INT                          DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE addresses (
  address_id         INT            IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  customer_id        INT            NOT NULL,
  line1              VARCHAR(60)    NOT NULL,
  line2              VARCHAR(60)                  DEFAULT NULL,
  city               VARCHAR(40)    NOT NULL,
  state              VARCHAR(2)     NOT NULL,
  zip_code           VARCHAR(10)    NOT NULL,
  phone              VARCHAR(12)    NOT NULL,
  disabled           TINYINT     NOT NULL      DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT addresses_fk_customers
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_id)
    REFERENCES customers (customer_id)
);

CREATE TABLE orders (
  order_id           INT            IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  customer_id        INT            NOT NULL,
  order_date         DATETIME       NOT NULL,
  ship_amount        DECIMAL(10,2)  NOT NULL,
  tax_amount         DECIMAL(10,2)  NOT NULL,
  ship_date          DATETIME                    DEFAULT NULL,
  ship_address_id    INT            NOT NULL,
  card_type          VARCHAR(50)    NOT NULL,
  card_number        CHAR(16)       NOT NULL,
  card_expires       CHAR(7)        NOT NULL,
  billing_address_id  INT           NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT orders_fk_customers
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_id)
    REFERENCES customers (customer_id)
);

CREATE TABLE order_items (
  item_id            INT            IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  order_id           INT            NOT NULL,
  product_id         INT            NOT NULL,
  item_price         DECIMAL(10,2)  NOT NULL,
  discount_amount    DECIMAL(10,2)  NOT NULL,
  quantity           INT            NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT items_fk_orders
    FOREIGN KEY (order_id)
    REFERENCES orders (order_id), 
  CONSTRAINT items_fk_products
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id)
    REFERENCES products (product_id)
);

CREATE TABLE administrators (
  admin_id           INT            IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  email_address      VARCHAR(255)   NOT NULL,
  password           VARCHAR(255)   NOT NULL,
  first_name         VARCHAR(255)   NOT NULL,
  last_name          VARCHAR(255)   NOT NULL
);

-- Insert data into the tables

SET IDENTITY_INSERT categories ON;  

INSERT INTO categories (category_id, category_name) VALUES
(1, 'Guitars'),
(2, 'Basses'),
(3, 'Drums'), 
(4, 'Keyboards');
SET IDENTITY_INSERT categories OFF;  


SET IDENTITY_INSERT products ON;  

INSERT INTO products (product_id, category_id, product_code, product_name, description, list_price, discount_percent, date_added) VALUES
(1, 1, 'strat', 'Fender Stratocaster', 'The Fender Stratocaster is the electric guitar design that changed the world. New features include a tinted neck, parchment pickguard and control knobs, and a ''70s-style logo. Includes select alder body, 21-fret maple neck with your choice of a rosewood or maple fretboard, 3 single-coil pickups, vintage-style tremolo, and die-cast tuning keys. This guitar features a thicker bridge block for increased sustain and a more stable point of contact with the strings. At this low price, why play anything but the real thing?\r\n\r\nFeatures:\r\n\r\n* New features:\r\n* Thicker bridge block\r\n* 3-ply parchment pick guard\r\n* Tinted neck', '699.00', '30.00', '2017-10-30 09:32:40'),
(2, 1, 'les_paul', 'Gibson Les Paul', 'This Les Paul guitar offers a carved top and humbucking pickups. It has a simple yet elegant design. Cutting-yet-rich tone?the hallmark of the Les Paul?pours out of the 490R and 498T Alnico II magnet humbucker pickups, which are mounted on a carved maple top with a mahogany back. The faded finish models are equipped with BurstBucker Pro pickups and a mahogany top. This guitar includes a Gibson hardshell case (Faded and satin finish models come with a gig bag) and a limited lifetime warranty.\r\n\r\nFeatures:\r\n\r\n* Carved maple top and mahogany back (Mahogany top on faded finish models)\r\n* Mahogany neck, ''59 Rounded Les Paul\r\n* Rosewood fingerboard (Ebony on Alpine white)\r\n* Tune-O-Matic bridge with stopbar\r\n* Chrome or gold hardware\r\n* 490R and 498T Alnico 2 magnet humbucker pickups (BurstBucker Pro on faded finish models)\r\n* 2 volume and 2 tone knobs, 3-way switch', '1199.00', '30.00', '2017-12-05 16:33:13'),
(3, 1, 'sg', 'Gibson SG', 'This Gibson SG electric guitar takes the best of the ''62 original and adds the longer and sturdier neck joint of the late ''60s models. All the classic features you''d expect from a historic guitar. Hot humbuckers go from rich, sweet lightning to warm, tingling waves of sustain. A silky-fast rosewood fretboard plays like a dream. The original-style beveled mahogany body looks like a million bucks. Plus, Tune-O-Matic bridge and chrome hardware. Limited lifetime warranty. Includes hardshell case.\r\n\r\nFeatures:\r\n\r\n* Double-cutaway beveled mahogany body\r\n* Set mahogany neck with rounded ''50s profile\r\n* Bound rosewood fingerboard with trapezoid inlays\r\n* Tune-O-Matic bridge with stopbar tailpiece\r\n* Chrome hardware\r\n* 490R humbucker in the neck position\r\n* 498T humbucker in the bridge position\r\n* 2 volume knobs, 2 tone knobs, 3-way switch\r\n* 24-3/4" scale', '2517.00', '52.00', '2018-02-04 11:04:31'),
(4, 1, 'fg700s', 'Yamaha FG700S', 'The Yamaha FG700S solid top acoustic guitar has the ultimate combo for projection and pure tone. The expertly braced spruce top speaks clearly atop the rosewood body. It has a rosewood fingerboard, rosewood bridge, die-cast tuners, body and neck binding, and a tortoise pickguard.\r\n\r\nFeatures:\r\n\r\n* Solid Sitka spruce top\r\n* Rosewood back and sides\r\n* Rosewood fingerboard\r\n* Rosewood bridge\r\n* White/black body and neck binding\r\n* Die-cast tuners\r\n* Tortoise pickguard\r\n* Limited lifetime warranty', '489.99', '38.00', '2018-06-01 11:12:59'),
(5, 1, 'washburn', 'Washburn D10S', 'The Washburn D10S acoustic guitar is superbly crafted with a solid spruce top and mahogany back and sides for exceptional tone. A mahogany neck and rosewood fingerboard make fretwork a breeze, while chrome Grover-style machines keep you perfectly tuned. The Washburn D10S comes with a limited lifetime warranty.\r\n\r\nFeatures:\r\n\r\n    * Spruce top\r\n    * Mahogany back, sides\r\n    * Mahogany neck Rosewood fingerboard\r\n    * Chrome Grover-style machines', '299.00', '0.00', '2018-07-30 13:58:35'),
(6, 1, 'rodriguez', 'Rodriguez Caballero 11', 'Featuring a carefully chosen, solid Canadian cedar top and laminated bubinga back and sides, the Caballero 11 classical guitar is a beauty to behold and play. The headstock and fretboard are of Indian rosewood. Nickel-plated tuners and Silver-plated frets are installed to last a lifetime. The body binding and wood rosette are exquisite.\r\n\r\nThe Rodriguez Guitar is hand crafted and glued to create precise balances. From the invisible careful sanding, even inside the body, that ensures the finished instrument''s purity of tone, to the beautifully unique rosette inlays around the soundhole and on the back of the neck, each guitar is a credit to its luthier and worthy of being handed down from one generation to another.\r\n\r\nThe tone, resonance and beauty of fine guitars are all dependent upon the wood from which they are made. The wood used in the construction of Rodriguez guitars is carefully chosen and aged to guarantee the highest quality. No wood is purchased before the tree has been cut down, and at least 2 years must elapse before the tree is turned into lumber. The wood has to be well cut from the log. The grain must be close and absolutely vertical. The shop is totally free from humidity.', '415.00', '39.00', '2018-07-30 14:12:41'),
(7, 2, 'precision', 'Fender Precision', 'The Fender Precision bass guitar delivers the sound, look, and feel today''s bass players demand. This bass features that classic P-Bass old-school design. Each Precision bass boasts contemporary features and refinements that make it an excellent value. Featuring an alder body and a split single-coil pickup, this classic electric bass guitar lives up to its Fender legacy.\r\n\r\nFeatures:\r\n\r\n* Body: Alder\r\n* Neck: Maple, modern C shape, tinted satin urethane finish\r\n* Fingerboard: Rosewood or maple (depending on color)\r\n* 9-1/2" Radius (241 mm)\r\n* Frets: 20 Medium-jumbo frets\r\n* Pickups: 1 Standard Precision Bass split single-coil pickup (Mid)\r\n* Controls: Volume, Tone\r\n* Bridge: Standard vintage style with single groove saddles\r\n* Machine heads: Standard\r\n* Hardware: Chrome\r\n* Pickguard: 3-Ply Parchment\r\n* Scale Length: 34" (864 mm)\r\n* Width at Nut: 1-5/8" (41.3 mm)\r\n* Unique features: Knurled chrome P Bass knobs, Fender transition logo', '799.99', '30.00', '2018-06-01 11:29:35'),
(8, 2, 'hofner', 'Hofner Icon', 'With authentic details inspired by the original, the Hofner Icon makes the legendary violin bass available to the rest of us. Don''t get the idea that this a just a "nowhere man" look-alike. This quality instrument features a real spruce top and beautiful flamed maple back and sides. The semi-hollow body and set neck will give you the warm, round tone you expect from the violin bass.\r\n\r\nFeatures:\r\n\r\n* Authentic details inspired by the original\r\n* Spruce top\r\n* Flamed maple back and sides\r\n* Set neck\r\n* Rosewood fretboard\r\n* 30" scale\r\n* 22 frets\r\n* Dot inlay', '499.99', '25.00', '2018-07-30 14:18:33'),
(9, 3, 'ludwig', 'Ludwig 5-piece Drum Set with Cymbals', 'This product includes a Ludwig 5-piece drum set and a Zildjian starter cymbal pack.\r\n\r\nWith the Ludwig drum set, you get famous Ludwig quality. This set features a bass drum, two toms, a floor tom, and a snare?each with a wrapped finish. Drum hardware includes LA214FP bass pedal, snare stand, cymbal stand, hi-hat stand, and a throne.\r\n\r\nWith the Zildjian cymbal pack, you get a 14" crash, 18" crash/ride, and a pair of 13" hi-hats. Sound grooves and round hammer strikes in a simple circular pattern on the top surface of these cymbals magnify the basic sound of the distinctive alloy.\r\n\r\nFeatures:\r\n\r\n* Famous Ludwig quality\r\n* Wrapped finishes\r\n* 22" x 16" kick drum\r\n* 12" x 10" and 13" x 11" toms\r\n* 16" x 16" floor tom\r\n* 14" x 6-1/2" snare drum kick pedal\r\n* Snare stand\r\n* Straight cymbal stand hi-hat stand\r\n* FREE throne', '699.99', '30.00', '2018-07-30 12:46:40'),
(10, 3, 'tama', 'Tama 5-Piece Drum Set with Cymbals', 'The Tama 5-piece Drum Set is the most affordable Tama drum kit ever to incorporate so many high-end features.\r\n\r\nWith over 40 years of experience, Tama knows what drummers really want. Which is why, no matter how long you''ve been playing the drums, no matter what budget you have to work with, Tama has the set you need, want, and can afford. Every aspect of the modern drum kit was exhaustively examined and reexamined and then improved before it was accepted as part of the Tama design. Which is why, if you start playing Tama now as a beginner, you''ll still enjoy playing it when you''ve achieved pro-status. That''s how good these groundbreaking new drums are.\r\n\r\nOnly Tama comes with a complete set of genuine Meinl HCS cymbals. These high-quality brass cymbals are made in Germany and are sonically matched so they sound great together. They are even lathed for a more refined tonal character. The set includes 14" hi-hats, 16" crash cymbal, and a 20" ride cymbal.\r\n\r\nFeatures:\r\n\r\n* 100% poplar 6-ply/7.5mm shells\r\n* Precise bearing edges\r\n* 100% glued finishes\r\n* Original small lugs\r\n* Drum heads\r\n* Accu-tune bass drum hoops\r\n* Spur brackets\r\n* Tom holder\r\n* Tom brackets', '799.99', '15.00', '2018-07-30 13:14:15');
SET IDENTITY_INSERT products OFF;  

SET IDENTITY_INSERT customers ON;  

INSERT INTO customers (customer_id, email_address, password, first_name, last_name, shipping_address_id, billing_address_id) VALUES
(1, 'allan.sherwood@yahoo.com', '650215acec746f0e32bdfff387439eefc1358737', 'Allan', 'Sherwood', 1, 2),
(2, 'barryz@gmail.com', '3f563468d42a448cb1e56924529f6e7bbe529cc7', 'Barry', 'Zimmer', 3, 3),
(3, 'christineb@solarone.com', 'ed19f5c0833094026a2f1e9e6f08a35d26037066', 'Christine', 'Brown', 4, 4),
(4, 'david.goldstein@hotmail.com', 'b444ac06613fc8d63795be9ad0beaf55011936ac', 'David', 'Goldstein', 5, 6),
(5, 'erinv@gmail.com', '109f4b3c50d7b0df729d299bc6f8e9ef9066971f', 'Erin', 'Valentino', 7, 7),
(6, 'frankwilson@sbcglobal.net', '3ebfa301dc59196f18593c45e519287a23297589', 'Frank Lee', 'Wilson', 8, 8),
(7, 'gary_hernandez@yahoo.com', '1ff2b3704aede04eecb51e50ca698efd50a1379b', 'Gary', 'Hernandez', 9, 10),
(8, 'heatheresway@mac.com', '911ddc3b8f9a13b5499b6bc4638a2b4f3f68bf23', 'Heather', 'Esway', 11, 12);
SET IDENTITY_INSERT customers OFF;  


SET IDENTITY_INSERT addresses ON;  

INSERT INTO addresses (address_id, customer_id, line1, line2, city, state, zip_code, phone, disabled) VALUES
(1, 1, '100 East Ridgewood Ave.', '', 'Paramus', 'NJ', '07652', '201-653-4472', 0),
(2, 1, '21 Rosewood Rd.', '', 'Woodcliff Lake', 'NJ', '07677', '201-653-4472', 0),
(3, 2, '16285 Wendell St.', '', 'Omaha', 'NE', '68135', '402-896-2576', 0),
(4, 3, '19270 NW Cornell Rd.', '', 'Beaverton', 'OR', '97006', '503-654-1291', 0),
(5, 4, '186 Vermont St.', 'Apt. 2', 'San Francisco', 'CA', '94110', '415-292-6651', 0),
(6, 4, '1374 46th Ave.', '', 'San Francisco', 'CA', '94129', '415-292-6651', 0),
(7, 5, '6982 Palm Ave.', '', 'Fresno', 'CA', '93711', '559-431-2398', 0),
(8, 6, '23 Mountain View St.', '', 'Denver', 'CO', '80208', '303-912-3852', 0),
(9, 7, '7361 N. 41st St.', 'Apt. B', 'New York', 'NY', '10012', '212-335-2093', 0),
(10, 7, '3829 Broadway Ave.', 'Suite 2', 'New York', 'NY', '10012', '212-239-1208', 0),
(11, 8, '2381 Buena Vista St.', '', 'Los Angeles', 'CA', '90023', '213-772-5033', 0),
(12, 8, '291 W. Hollywood Blvd.', '', 'Los Angeles', 'CA', '90024', '213-391-2938', 0);
SET IDENTITY_INSERT addresses OFF;  


SET IDENTITY_INSERT orders ON;  

INSERT INTO orders (order_id, customer_id, order_date, ship_amount, tax_amount, ship_date, ship_address_id, card_type, card_number, card_expires, billing_address_id) VALUES
(1, 1, '2018-03-28 09:40:28', '5.00', '32.32', '2018-03-30 15:32:51', 1, 'Visa', '4111111111111111', '04/2020', 2),
(2, 2, '2018-03-28 11:23:20', '5.00', '0.00', '2018-03-29 12:52:14', 3, 'Visa', '4012888888881881', '08/2019', 3),
(3, 1, '2018-03-29 09:44:58', '10.00', '89.92', '2018-03-31 9:11:41', 1, 'Visa', '4111111111111111', '04/2017', 2),
(4, 3, '2018-03-30 15:22:31', '5.00', '0.00', '2018-04-03 16:32:21', 4, 'American Express', '378282246310005', '04/2016', 4),
(5, 4, '2018-03-31 05:43:11', '5.00', '0.00', '2018-04-02 14:21:12', 5, 'Visa', '4111111111111111', '04/2019', 6),
(6, 5, '2018-03-31 18:37:22', '5.00', '0.00', NULL, 7, 'Discover', '6011111111111117', '04/2019', 7),
(7, 6, '2018-04-01 23:11:12', '15.00', '0.00', '2018-04-03 10:21:35', 8, 'MasterCard', '5555555555554444', '04/2019', 8),
(8, 7, '2018-04-02 11:26:38', '5.00', '0.00', NULL, 9, 'Visa', '4012888888881881', '04/2019', 10),
(9, 4, '2018-04-03 12:22:31', '5.00', '0.00', NULL, 5, 'Visa', '4111111111111111', '04/2019', 6);
SET IDENTITY_INSERT orders OFF;  



SET IDENTITY_INSERT order_items ON;  

INSERT INTO order_items (item_id, order_id, product_id, item_price, discount_amount, quantity) VALUES
(1, 1, 2, '1199.00', '359.70', 1),
(2, 2, 4, '489.99', '186.20', 1),
(3, 3, 3, '2517.00', '1308.84', 1),
(4, 3, 6, '415.00', '161.85', 1),
(5, 4, 2, '1199.00', '359.70', 2),
(6, 5, 5, '299.00', '0.00', 1),
(7, 6, 5, '299.00', '0.00', 1),
(8, 7, 1, '699.00', '209.70', 1),
(9, 7, 7, '799.99', '240.00', 1),
(10, 7, 9, '699.99', '210.00', 1),
(11, 8, 10, '799.99', '120.00', 1),
(12, 9, 1, '699.00', '209.70', 1);
SET IDENTITY_INSERT order_items OFF;  

SET IDENTITY_INSERT administrators ON;  

INSERT INTO administrators (admin_id, email_address, password, first_name, last_name) VALUES
(1, 'admin@myguitarshop.com', '6a718fbd768c2378b511f8249b54897f940e9022', 'Admin', 'User'),
(2, 'joel@murach.com', '971e95957d3b74d70d79c20c94e9cd91b85f7aae', 'Joel', 'Murach'),
(3, 'mike@murach.com', '3f2975c819cefc686282456aeae3a137bf896ee8', 'Mike', 'Murach');
SET IDENTITY_INSERT administrators OFf;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the aggregation together:

```
SELECT * FROM (

    SELECT  c.email_address,
        COUNT(o.order_id) OVER (PARTITION BY c.customer_id) customer_orders,
        oi.order_total
    FROM customers c
    JOIN orders o ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
    JOIN (
        SELECT o.customer_id,
            SUM((oi.item_price - oi.discount_amount) * oi.quantity)  AS order_total
            FROM order_items oi
            GROUP BY ()
        ) AS oi
    ON o.order_id = oi.order_id
) c
WHERE c.customer_orders > 1

ORDER BY order_total DESC
```

Comment: but this is not the same you see, with your query i am only getting 2 rows, and am I not supposed to get a row per order? with my query I get a row per order.

Comment: Should be fixed now

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 39
The multi-part identifier "oi.order_id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 44
The multi-part identifier "o.customer_id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 41
The multi-part identifier "o.customer_id" could not be bound.

Comment: Sorry really sloppy of me

Answer (score 0):

I think I would try to filter out the customs who do not have more than 1 order first and then CROSS APPLY for the order line total after that.  Consider this:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
    (SELECT c.customer_id,c.email_address, COUNT(*) order_count from customers c
    INNER JOIN orders o on o.customer_id = c.customer_id
    GROUP BY c.customer_id,c.email_address
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )    
SELECT c.email_address, c.order_Count,  t1.order_total
FROM CTE c
INNER JOIN ORders o on C.customer_id = o.Customer_ID
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM( (oi.Item_Price - oi.discount_amount) * oi.quantity) as order_total 
                FROM order_items oi 
                WHERE oi.order_id = o.order_id GROUP BY oi.order_id) t1 
ORDER BY order_total DESC
```

Comment: real pro, thank you, will study those functions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to JMabee's advice, https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-user-defined-functions/sql-server-table-valued-functions/ and APPLY clause I developed this answer, it works on the current database but could have flaws, any advice is welcomed, I modified it to order first by the quantity of items and then by the price in desc order, result is the same. Don't know how to test efficiency.

```
USE my_guitar_shop;
go

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS myFun1;
go
CREATE FUNCTION myFun1 (
    @customer_id INT
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT 
        o.order_id,
         COUNT(customer_id) OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id) AS order_count,
         SUM( (oi.Item_Price - oi.discount_amount) * oi.quantity) AS order_total,
         SUM(COUNT(oi.quantity)) OVER (PARTITION BY oi.order_id) AS items_quantity
    FROM
        orders o
    JOIN order_items oi
        ON o.order_id = oi.order_id

    WHERE
        customer_id = @customer_id
        GROUP BY customer_id, o.order_id, oi.quantity, oi.order_id
;
go

select  email_address, order_total, order_count
from customers c
cross apply myFun1(c.customer_id)
where order_count > 1
order by items_quantity DESC, order_total DESC;
go
```